# Theorem 3.16 from the book by D. S. Jones, The theory of generalised functions

Tags: proof-explanation, distribution-theory

I am reading D. S. Jones' book, *The theory of generalised functions*, and this question is specifically about theorem 3.16 on page 81.
To make this post self-consistent I'll give a bit of context. Let's start with the definitions.

*A good function $\gamma(x)$ is defined as a function acting on reals, infinitely differentiable and such that it and all its derivatives are a $O\left(|x|^{-N}\right)$, for all $N$.*

*A generalized function is by definition a family of good functions $\{\gamma_n(x)\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that the limit exists $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\gamma_n(x)\gamma(x)\mathrm{d}x$ for all good $\gamma(x)$.*

I also report a lemma, without proving it.

*The following property is valid for all good functions: $$\max_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\left\{(1+x^2)^{\alpha} \left|\gamma^{(p)}(x)\right| \right\}\leq \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^n\max_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\left\{(1+x^2)^{\alpha+n} \left|\gamma^{(p+n)}(x)\right|\right\}$$
where $\alpha\geq 0$ and $p\in\mathbb{N}_0$.*

Having said that, let's get to the doubt.
Theorem 3.16 states that:

*Whatever the generalized function is $ \left\{\gamma_n(x)\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}} $, there exist $k$, $r$, and a constant $K$ such that $$ \left| \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \gamma_n(x) \gamma(x) \mathrm{d}x\right| \leq K \max_{x\in\mathbb{R}}(1+x^2)^{k/2}\gamma^{(r)}(x)$$ for all good $\gamma$.*

He begins the proof by noting that:

$$\begin{split}\left| \int_{-\infty}^\infty \gamma_n(x) \gamma(x) \mathrm{d}x\right| &\leq \int_{-\infty}^\infty |\gamma_n(x)| \mathrm{d}x \cdot \max_{x\in\mathbb{R}}| \gamma(x)|\\
&\underbrace{\leq}_{\text{Lemma}} \underbrace{ \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^s \int_{-\infty}^\infty |\gamma_n(x)| \mathrm{d}x}_{C_{s,n} \text{ indipendent of }\gamma} \cdot \max_{x\in\mathbb{R}}(1+x^2)^{s}| \gamma^{(s)}(x)|\end{split}$$

and he says that the proof would be concluded if for some $s$ the constants $C_{s,n}$ would be bounded as $n$ varies. In order to prove this, he proceeds by contradiction, assuming that this is not true, **and so equivalently that** chosen any $k$ and $s$, you will always find an index $n$ beyond which $ \left| \int_{-\infty}^\infty \gamma_n(x) \gamma(x) \mathrm{d}x\right| > L_n\cdot \max_{x\in\mathbb{R}}(1+x^2)^{k/2}| \gamma^{(s)}(x)| $, no matter how $L_n$ is large.

It is precisely the passage "and so equivalently that" that I dispute. For me, the absurd hypothesis that could be set are at most two and I didn't quite understand which of the two he had in mind to follow, from what he wrote:

1. I assume by contradiction that, whatever $s$ is, the sequence $C_{s,n}$ is always unbounded;
2. I suppose absurdly that, however they are chosen $k,r$ and $K$, you can always find a good function $\tilde{\gamma}$ such that the sequence $ \left| \int_{-\infty}^\infty \gamma_n(x) \tilde{\gamma}(x) \mathrm{d}x\right| $ is not bounded as $n$ varies.

By choosing the first hypothesis, it does not seem to me that much can be deduced, because if the upper bounds are unlimited it does not mean that the sequence must also be unlimited.
The second hypothesis by contradiction instead allows free choice for the constants $k,r$ and $K$ (those of the statement of the theorem), but then the good function $\tilde{\gamma}(x)$ is "the one that comes out", but, instead, he bases the entire continuation of the proof on the possibility of choosing the good functions as he likes, in the way that is most convenient for him to reach a contradiction.

What am I missing? I can't believe that the passage highlighted by me is truly a logical error committed by the author. Much more likely I'm missing something and I ask for help in understanding this.

Thank you.

Comment: This might not help for this question, but just in case: these good functions are more commonly referred to as "Schwartz class functions" or simply "Schwartz functions" nowadays (named after Laurent Schwartz, not Hermann Schwarz). This way you can find more information on them if you're ever interested.

Comment: I've spent a decent chunk of time trying to make sense of Jones' logic looking at the proof directly in his book, but I fear I do have to agree that there might be a legitimate error, since, as you noticed, he relies extensively on the ability to choose $\gamma$ however he wants in the second half of the proof. I don't really see how to salvage this situation unless there really is a way to suitably modify the quantities $\max_{x\in\mathbb{R}}(1+x^2)^{s}| \gamma^{(s)}(x)|$... Though do take my opinion with a big grain of salt. Hopefully someone more knowledgeable can show up and help you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. Unfortunately I can't find a way to overcome this fault, and so I'm stuck, because I don't know another book or reference that approach distribution theory in the Lighthill way. And this particular theorem is not present in the original Lighthill book. Anyway, thank you again, how can I give you the bounty? I think you have to write your reply as an answer :)

Comment: I don't know, that is very kind of you but I wouldn't want to get a bounty only with pretty much a rephrasing of what you've mentioned just because it's confirmation from someone other than you that there might be an error. This might sound stupid, but I'd like to gain such kinds of rewards fairly and more confidently. I do hope that someone else will answer you with more panache so that your 50 points don't just vanish but get awarded to someone who would deserve it better. Cheers!

Comment: I suggest a closer look at pp.109-111 and the proof of Thm 3.3-1 (pp. 84 -86) of the book "Distribution theory and transform analysis" by A.H. Zemanian.

Comment: Notice that in there distributions  of $D^{*}(\Omega)$ are defined as continuous linear forms on $\mathbb{D}(\Omega)$ and distribution of $\mathcal{E}^{*}(\Omega)$ are distributions of $\mathbb{D}^{*}(\Omega)$ with compact support. After defining $\mathbb{D}(\Omega)$ one proves its sequential completeness [instead of using that definition of a distribution as a sequence...see e.g. the PDE book of Renardy and Rogers, p. 134]..

Comment: Also, see p. 132 of that book for the similar fact to the one you are studying for $\mathbb{D}^{*}(\Omega)$. The corresponding statement for $\mathcal{E}^{*}(\Omega)$ usually appears as an exercise. In both references the proof by contradiction is clear IMHO